# How to load org.apache.maven.settings.Settings outside of a Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I need to access `settings.xml` from outside a Maven plugin. How do I instantiate a `org.apache.maven.settings.Settings` that correpsonds to the user's settings.xml?

Comment: Why do you need to access it outside a Maven plugin? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I use encrypted passwords in settings.xml as part of my build process. When debugging my application locally, I want to reuse those same passwords at runtime.

Comment: I don't recommend that cause the passwords in settings are for the build process and for runtime of your application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from [Fitnesse Maven Classpath plugin cannot resolve remote dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37005432/14731):

```
/**
 * @return the Maven settings
 * @throws SettingsBuildingException if the file cannot be loaded
 */
private Settings getMavenSettings() throws SettingsBuildingException 
{
    String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File userMavenConfigurationHome = new File(userHome, ".m2");
    String envM2Home = System.getenv("M2_HOME");
    File DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE = new File(userMavenConfigurationHome, "settings.xml");
    File DEFAULT_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_FILE = new File(System.getProperty("maven.home", envM2Home != null ? envM2Home : ""),
        "conf/settings.xml");
    SettingsBuildingRequest settingsBuildingRequest = new DefaultSettingsBuildingRequest();
    settingsBuildingRequest.setSystemProperties(System.getProperties());
    settingsBuildingRequest.setUserSettingsFile(DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE);
    settingsBuildingRequest.setGlobalSettingsFile(DEFAULT_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_FILE);

    DefaultSettingsBuilderFactory mvnSettingBuilderFactory = new DefaultSettingsBuilderFactory();
    DefaultSettingsBuilder settingsBuilder = mvnSettingBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    SettingsBuildingResult settingsBuildingResult = settingsBuilder.build(settingsBuildingRequest);
    return settingsBuildingResult.getEffectiveSettings();
}
```

Comment: +1. FitNesse was the first test automation tool that I learned. I still pull general solutions from out of old FitNesse solutions.